# Font size in portrait vs. landscape on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am developing a mobile website but have encountered this problem - a font size of 14px is displaying much larger in landscape than in portrait. However, it seems to be based on the fact that the Div size is set to 100% so in landscape it is obviously wider. What I don't understand is why that should affect the size of the font given that 14px isn't a relative size but a fixed one?

Is there an explanation for this that I am missing? Appreciate any answers (so long as you don't tell me I'm an idiot for missing something obvious!)

Comment: On what device in what browser?

Comment: It's on an iphone using Safari mobile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple rescales the font-size when the viewport changes to increase readability. It doesn't matter that the font-size is set to something absolute like 14px. To disable it, you can use the following CSS:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Comment: Ich, please don't do this. It prevents _any_ font resizing, even with page zoom on desktop browsers.

Comment: He can always set the adjust to something that fits the zooming, changing none to a percentage. That is simply the way to make sure his text is the size he intended it to be...

Comment: The point is you're removing an adjustment that some users depend upon to be able to read text.

Comment: That is true, definitely worth thinking about. For the record, this worked html {-webkit-text-size-adjust:none}

Comment: Whenever you change the default behavior expected by users, you must ensure that you provide a good alternative so that you improve usability, not degrade it.

Comment: If [this post](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/04/iphone-text-resizing/) is correct, you can set the value to `100%` to get the best of both worlds.  iOS will not automatically resize the text when the orientation changes, but the user can still do so if need be.  Note that I have not tried this, but it seems reasonable enough.

Answer (score 3):

@hotshot309's comment (linking to this post from [55 Minutes](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/04/iphone-text-resizing/)) is the correct answer, but I fear as a comment it isn't getting the attention it deserves. What the OP (and likely anybody arriving here) should be using is this:

`-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;`

If you set it to `none`, the user won't be able to scale even if they want to (something that I, for one, often do on desktop when I don't feel like violating the monitor's personal space with my face). Using `100%` prevents webkit from doing its default scaling while still allowing users the freedom to do so themselves.

Comment: I just can't seem to get this method to work on my old IOS 7 safari/i-phone. But what I've been doing is defining my main body CSS for 1rem font sizes for all browsers, and then in my @media selectors for small -phone screens, I set the portrait and landscape body fonts sizes to 0.9rem and 0.7rem respectively. It seems once I fine tune that single ratio, all other font size % can be identical for the landscape and portrait cases, with very close results after turning the device sideways and back. Maybe this is better than coding a webkit correction for a single brand of mobile browser?