# CSS: how to do away with automatic rescaling of font-size on Safari

Tags: css, safari, font-size, portrait

Note: I'm posting this question again, with very slight modification, as the first time the issue didn't get resolved. The earlier question is found here: [CSS: Disabling automatic rescaling of font-size on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860866/css-disabling-automatic-rescaling-of-font-size-on-iphone]), but as I said it's almost identical; it has one answer that unfortunately didn't clarify much for me...]

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761212/font-size-in-portrait-vs-landscape-on-mobile-devices), the Apple iPhone (i.e. Safari) rescales the font-size when the viewport changes (i.e. from portrait to landscape or vice versa).

The accepted answer to that question says that, in order to disable this behaviour, one should add:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Accordingly, my main question is why, when I view the following HTML test-file on my iPhone, the fixed-sized font is STILL rendered bigger in landscape as compared to portrait view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <title>Untitled Document</title> 
        <style> 
            p { 
              font-size:24px;
             -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
             } 
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body> 
        <p>This is an example text</p> 
    </body>     
</html>
```

(Note: in other posts I've also seen '100%' instead of 'none', which is probably preferable, but the distinction seems irrelevant here, as neither works.)

However, I'd also like to have it confirmed that the Apple iPhone - and possibly other Apple devices - are the ONLY devices displaying this (to me, annoying) behaviour... is that true?

Incidentally, I find it annoying because now I can't test properly on my iPhone, knowing that my website (i.e. font-size) is rendered differently on other mobile devices (and I don't fully trust online emulators).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's to do with font sizing you use apparently, on this site I use the following css:

```
html, body
{
    font-size: 100%; /* equivalent to 16px */
}
```

for the style sheet that effects the fonts for mobile I only put sizes that are larger than 16px for the sake of peoples eye sight, eg

```
 h2
{
  font-size:1.5rem; 
  /* notice the use of rem as compared to em - I don't use px for font sizes so I don't know about that */
}
```

http://www.awri.com.au/research_and_development/metabolomics_facility/

FYI my meta tag is:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=yes,initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, when I include the font-size: 100% for html and body, as well as the em (or rem)-fontsize instead of the pixels, the text STILL gets rendered bigger in landscape view than in portrait view... Do you have a different experience?

Comment: Is this what you have in your header? Maybe it's that <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=yes,initial-scale=1" />

Comment: You're right! Thank you very much and I'll accept the answer right now. And good evening [I take it you are in the US or thereabout - I'm in Holland and it's early in the morning here. ;-) ]

Comment: You beaut! My husband helped me with that a good while back. I'm in NSW Australia and it's coming up to 6pm.

Comment: That's funny, I'm watching the Australian Open right now (avid tennis fan). Thanks again and maybe later!